# Applying a style to input:active .className?

Tags: css

I have an Input of type submit:

```
 <input type="submit" class="redButton" value="Cancel"/>
```

But this style, on the active click doesn't apply. Does it not work on Inputs?

```
input:active .redbutton {
   -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Please tag your questions carefully. This is the second time I've had to correct the same tag misspelling on your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must write like that:

```
input.redbutton:active
```

But you probably want to use "focus" instead of active. So it must be:

```
input.redbutton:focus
```